# php syntax for set variable by existing or new

Tags: php, micro-optimization

Another micro-optim question. What is the php best way to set variable like in javascript *existing or new value*

`var a = a || false`

using

`$a = $a || false;`

we get error notice abour undefined variable `$a`. This variable may or may not be set in previous programm part. (Due plug-ins.) It can be done with extra condition before. Stg like *if isset(...*

The question is **does elegant 1 row solution exists?**

Comment: `$a = (isset($a))? $a: false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a = isset ($a)? $a:false`

This is the best way for doing so without warnings

Answer (score 1):

Solution exists:

In general:

```
$a = isset($a) ? $a : false;
```

Some example with handling `$_GET` array.

```
$a = isset($_GET['someParam']) ? $_GET['someParam'] : false;
```

You can use everything instead of `$a` or `$_GET['someParam']`.